Automate deactivation or reactivation of a flow
For the import of Knowledge Article I would like to temporary deactivate the flow but then reactivate it again once Articles upload has finished.
How can I automate this action?
Also in the end I would like to open Flow in UI to verify that it was deactivated or activated.
I tried the following script to change status of the flow to be Obsolete
flowName="MyBeautifulFlowBreakingImport"
cloneFlow="src/flows/$flowName.flow-meta.xml"
tempFlow="temp.flow-meta.xml"
sed -e "s|<status>Active</status>|<status>Obsolete</status>|g" $cloneFlow > $tempFlow
mv $tempFlow $cloneFlow
sf project deploy start -c -m Flow:$flowName
rm -f $tempFlow
flowId=$(sf data query -q "SELECT Id FROM FlowDefinition WHERE DeveloperName = '$flowName'" -t --json | jq '.result.records[0].Id' -r)
sf org open -p "/$flowId"

and back from Obsolete to Active
flowName="MyBeautifulFlowBreakingImport"
cloneFlow="src/flows/$flowName.flow-meta.xml"
tempFlow="temp.flow-meta.xml"
sed -e "s|<status>Obsolete</status>|<status>Active</status>|g" $cloneFlow > $tempFlow
mv $tempFlow $cloneFlow
sf project deploy start -c -m Flow:$flowName
rm -f $tempFlow
flowId=$(sf data query -q "SELECT Id FROM FlowDefinition WHERE DeveloperName = '$flowName'" -t --json | jq '.result.records[0].Id' -r)
sf org open -p "/$flowId"

but apparently this doesn't help to deactivate or activate the Flow

So actually to deactivate or activate the flow we need to deploy FlowDefinition metadata file, not the Flow metadata file.
So, to deactivate the flow we need to deploy empty metadata file like following
flowName="MyBeautifulFlowBreakingImport"
file="src/main/default/flowDefinitions/$flowName.flowDefinition-meta.xml"
backupFile="backupFD.flowDefinition-meta.xml"
sf project retrieve start -m FlowDefinition:$flowName
mv $file $backupFile
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<FlowDefinition xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"/>' > $file
sf project deploy start -c -m FlowDefinition:$flowName

flowId=$(sf data query -q "SELECT Id FROM FlowDefinition WHERE DeveloperName = '$flowName'" -t --json | jq '.result.records[0].Id' -r)
sf org open -p "/$flowId"

and to reactivate it back again, we need to deploy the flow definition like which has the active number like this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlowDefinition xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <activeVersionNumber>1</activeVersionNumber>
</FlowDefinition>

but since there might be active version of flow distinct from the first version, instead we can just backup the activated flow definition metadata and restore it afterwards like this:
flowName="MyBeautifulFlowBreakingImport"
file="src/main/default/flowDefinitions/$flowName.flowDefinition-meta.xml"
backupFile="backupFD.flowDefinition-meta.xml"
cp $backupFile $file 
sf project deploy start -c -m FlowDefinition:$flowName

flowId=$(sf data query -q "SELECT Id FROM FlowDefinition WHERE DeveloperName = '$flowName'" -t --json | jq '.result.records[0].Id' -r)
sf org open -p "/$flowId"

